# Module '"@angular/fire/auth"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuth'.ts(2305)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am having this error with an import

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth"; Error-. Module '"@angular/fire/auth"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuth'.ts(2305)
```

And if import it from `@angular/fire/compat/auth` then getting bellow error in terminal:

```js
Time: 213ms

ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:28 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                              ~~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                 ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:49 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                   ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:50 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                    ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. 

27 };
   ~

    
    ERROR in src/app/services/firebase.service.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/fire/compat"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuth'.
    
    2 import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/compat/";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    

Date: 2021-11-13T07:45:51.865Z - Hash: ff0e2da18163e6a524d5
5 unchanged chunks

Time: 330ms

ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:28 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                              ~~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                 ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:49 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                   ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:26:50 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

26     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                    ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. 

27 };
   ~
node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:13:55 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

13 export declare const USE_EMULATOR: InjectionToken<[url: string]>;
                                                         ~
node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:13:63 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

13 export declare const USE_EMULATOR: InjectionToken<[url: string]>;
                                                                 ~
node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:13:64 - error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.    

13 export declare const USE_EMULATOR: InjectionToken<[url: string]>;
                                                                  ~
node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:13:65 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

13 export declare const USE_EMULATOR: InjectionToken<[url: string]>;
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It sounds like the first thing to do is make sure you're running a new enough version of typescript. Seems like 4.1 or higher is required. What Angular version are you on? I'm on 6 and am concerned that it's too low a version.

Comment: I found a workaround  for this issue using a downgrade to  "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5", and a subsequent npm update.

Comment: I've got the same problem when I import firestore.

Comment: @S.Slusky I'm using typescript 4.5.5. This does not help me much. I've tried 4.1.1 it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have following configuration in my project where I was facing the issue and Its working now.
package.json file>

```
       {
      "name": "something",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
        "@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
        "@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
        "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
....
some other packages 
....
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.2",
        "firebase": "^7.24.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
        "@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~3.8.3"
      }
    }
```

changing to `"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5"`, and typescript version for project `"typescript": "~3.8.3"` and then deleting node_modules and fresh npm install worked for me.
Now I am able to import it without error as  `import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';`